# When I add a for loop to the top of my code, my program crashes. Why?

Tags: c, loops, marquee

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //int num_of_signs,x;
    //scanf("%d", &num_of_signs);
    //for (x=0; x<num_of_signs; x++){
        int num_of_chars, i;
        char sign[30], two_sign[60];
        fgets(sign, sizeof(sign), stdin);
        scanf("%d", &num_of_chars);

        sign[strlen(sign) - 1] = '\0'; // discard '\n'
        strcpy(two_sign, sign);
        strcat(two_sign, sign);
        for (i = 0; sign[num_of_chars + i]; i++){
        printf("[%.*s]\n", num_of_chars, two_sign + i);
        }
   // }
    return 0;
}
```

The original code without the for loop does this:

```
Input: 
Hello World!
5

Output:
[Hello]
[ello ]
[llo W]
[lo Wo]
[o Wor]
[ Worl]
[World]
[orld!]
[rld! ]
[ld! H]
[d! He]
[! Hel]
```

When I add in a loop to do this with multiple inputs, my program crashes. To be specific, it crashes after I input my first string that I want as my sign. I can't figure out why....

What I want it to do is this:

```
Input:  
3
Hello World!
5
Farewell
10
Sad
2



Output: 
Sign #1:
[Hello]
[ello ]
[llo W]
[lo Wo]
[o Wor]
[ Worl]
[World]
[orld!]
[rld! ]
[ld! H]
[d! He]
[! Hel]

Sign #2:
[Farewell ]

Sign #3:
[Sa]
[ad]
[d ]
[ S]
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix `scanf` and `fgets`. Either use `scanf` for all input (replace the `fgets` with `scanf("%29[^\n],sign)`), or read lines with `fgets` and extract the numbers with `sscanf`, e.g. `fgets(buffer,sizeof buffer,stdin); sscanf(buffer,"%d",&num_of_chars);`

Answer (score 4):

```
    scanf("%d", &num_of_chars);
```

leaves the newline in the stream. Hence, the next call to `fgets` returns a line that has just the newline character.

You need to add code to ignore the rest of the line after that.

Add a function

```
void ignoreRestOfLine(FILE* fp)
{
   int c;
   while ( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

and call it right after the above `scanf` line as:

```
ignoreRestOfLine(stdin);
```

Also, always check that calls to `fgets` and `scanf` succeed before proceeding to use the data that are supposed to be read in.

Change

```
    fgets(sign, sizeof(sign), stdin);
    scanf("%d", &num_of_chars);
```

to

```
    if ( fgets(sign, sizeof(sign), stdin) == NULL )
    {
       // Deal with error.
    }

    if ( scanf("%d", &num_of_chars) != 1 )
    {
       // Deal with error.
    }

    // Skip rest of the line
    ignoreRestOfLine(stdin);
```